# Pager in EEX Templates Without Ecto - Elixir and Phoenix

Tags: html, templates, elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to list many items in an HTML page. There are too many items to display at once within reason. I have seen tools that work with Ecto to handle pagers in EEX templates. However, in my controller, I am pulling this data from an external data source and cannot query it with Ecto. Template file inventory.html.eex below.

```html
<div class="section-content">
  <div class="section-row">
    <div class="section-cell">
      <h3> Current Inventory: </h3>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Product Title</th>
            <th>Product ID</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
      <%= for product <- @products do %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= product["title"] %></td>
            <td><%= product["id"]%></td>
         </tr>
      <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is a good solution for handling pagination of this data?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [scriviner_html](https://github.com/mgwidmann/scrivener_html) library for pagination helpers in your templates.
This just requires populating a `%Scriviner.Page{}` struct from your controller and passing it through to `render`.

The [Page](https://github.com/drewolson/scrivener/blob/master/lib/scrivener/page.ex#L14) struct is quite simple, so you can populate it from a list or API response from the external source:

```
defstruct [:entries, :page_number, :page_size, :total_entries, :total_pages]
```